# Get roadname from gmaps by coordinates

Tags: google-maps

Is there a way, with the Google Maps API, or some other way with Gmaps, to receive the roadname from GPS coordinates?

Ex: [These example coordinates](https://www.google.com/maps?t=m&sll=51.611384,4.35159&sspn=0.0051168,0.0109864&q=%2b51%C2%B036%2740.98%22,%20%2b4%C2%B021%275.72%22&cid=0x0&output=classic) are on the dutch N259, or really close to.

Is there an easy way to just get the roadname ?

Answer (score 1):

you should use [Google Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=en&csw=1#ReverseGeocoding)

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way to let it prefer highway numbers over street addresses ?